# Why does images look with same intensity though they have different pixel values?

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I have read an image using skimage library. Then I diving each and every pixel value of the image by 1000 and then displayed the image. Both the images look exactly the same with no difference in intensity. Why does two images with different pixels values(though they are in proportion) look same?

Comment: Your question says you used `scikit-image` but you have tagged `python-imaging-library` rather than `scikit-image`? Please add your code so we can assist you properly - if we don't know **how** you displayed the image it is hard to know what's wrong. Also, please do the tour to get a better idea of how StackOverflow works. Thank you.

Comment: Probably because the function you're using to display the image automatically scales it. We can't know for sure unless we see your code. If you can't debug it by looking at the code and the images, how do you expect us to debug it *without* all of that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.